# Bound on tail of beta distribution

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with a beta distribution $\beta(j,k)$.  Is there a convenient upper bound for the left tail when $j$ and $k$ are large:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \leq \varepsilon) \leq ??
$$

Comment: markov inequality says that  $$P(X \ge a  ) \le   \frac{E(X)}{a}$$

Comment: Yes, but this is the wrong direction.

Comment: @James This gives a *lower* bound for $P(X\le \varepsilon)$, not an upper bound.

Comment: but we can write that as 1-P(X<=a)

Comment: @James, but your inequality is reversed...

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    P(X\leq \epsilon) &= \frac{1}{B(j,k)}\int_0^\epsilon t^{j-1}(1-t)^{k-1}dt\\
    &< \frac{1}{B(j,k)}\int_0^\epsilon t^{j-1} dt\\
    &= \frac{\epsilon^j}{jB(j,k)}
\end{align}